Torsion free module is the submodule of a free module
In this question  Embedding of a torsion free module into a free module, it is said that this proposition is well-known:

If $A$ is an integral domain and $M$ is torsion-free and finitely generated, then there is an injective $A$-module morphism $M\to A^{n}$ with some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$.

But I don't know how to prove this proposition.
In Embedding of a torsion-free module , Jingyu Liu says that we can take the tensor product of $M$ with $K$ (the quotient field of $R$) and find suitable basis. But I couldn't figure it out.

I have added the missing assumption that the module is finitely generated. It is also in the linked post.

Sorry I forgot to add this. Thanks!

Since $M$ is torsionfree, it embeds into $M \otimes_A Q(A)$. By choosing a basis of the finitely generated $Q(A)$-module $M \otimes_A Q(A)$, we see that $M$ is isomorphic to a submodule $M'$ of $Q(A)^n$ which is finitely generated over $A$. Let $p$ be the product of the denominators of a generating set. Then multiplication with $p$ is an automorphism of the module $Q(A)^n$, and by construction it maps $M'$ to a submodule of $A^n$.

I saw a question earlier that you didn't answer.

Oh $Q(A)$ is the quotient field (分式域) (I misunderstood it). Thank you very much!

@non-euclideangeometry ?
